# Спасите запятую! "Таким образом" общее для двух предложений иль нет?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые

> Доменико Фонтана занимается и реставрацией акведуков, таким образом в
>   Монти возвращается вода и становится возможным создание здесь виллы с
>   обширным парком для папы Сикста V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Таким образом* относится к  "возвращается и становится". По-другому невозможно союз *и* оправдать.

Comment: Некто чинит акведук - возвращает воду, а к созданию виллы некто отношения не имеет (это я рассуждаю вслух)...

Comment: А на вилле пить хотят... И парк поливать.

Comment: Кстати, **создавать** виллу — не слишком ли сильно? Это будет произведение искусства?

Comment: Весь текст о произведениях искусства.

Comment: И все-таки... По-моему, здания **создают** только виртуально на магнитном диске, а на земле - строят, возводят.